# DHCP-offer fails on dhcpserver - router-on-a-stick

Tags: vlan, dhcp

I am using packettracer to configure a network. The problem is that the router (that is acting as a router-on-a-stick) is not offering ip-addresses from its pool. The pc that act as the client belongs to vlan 30 and the interface fa0/1 on the switch is in acess-mode state. So no problem. And - the G0/1-interface to the router is configured as a trunk link. OK! AND - And the PC can communicate with ICMP-messages to the router if its configured static. So I do not understand why the router doesnt offer any address to the client?

When I click the DHCP-radiobutton on the pc-GUI I get the following error information:

**DHCP failed. APIPA is being used**

Router config for dhcp

```
HQ(config)#ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.193 255.255.255.192
HQ(config)#ip dhcp pool LAN
HQ(dhcp-config)#network 10.10.10.192 255.255.255.192
HQ(dhcp-config)#default-router 10.10.10.193
HQ(dhcp-config)#end
```

And the addressing info looks like this for vlan-30 on the router:

```
G0/0.30   10.10.10.193   255.255.255.192
```

And my config on the router for this subinterface

```
HQ(config-subif)#encapsulation dot1q 30
HQ(config-subif)#ip address 10.10.10.193 255.255.255.192
```

I add a screenshot here so you easily can see the topology of the network.

Would be  greatful if someone could see why the router wont offer the ip-addresses? May it have something to do with the native vlan that is VLAN 45?

cincerely

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've excluded all IP's available in the pool except for the network address:

```
HQ(dhcp-config)#network 10.10.10.192 255.255.255.192
```

indicates available IP addresses are 10.10.10.192 upto and including 10.10.10.255, and

```
HQ(config)#ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.10.193 255.255.255.192
```

Indicates that except for 10.10.10.192 these addresses cannot be used. So fix that last statement so the DHCP server actually has some addresses it can assign.

Comment: Thanks a lot - now I can see what I did wrong - I put the subnetmask in the exluded-syntax which is wrong. Thanks!!!